# Dynamic remove of text box in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have implemented a dynamic adding removing text boxes using a post i found in net. I succesfully added dynamic text boxes but removing them is not working. Please see my design and jquery

```
   <td style="font-size: large; vertical-align:top" >
       Mobile:
        </td>

        <td valign="top" >
            <div id="divAdd">
                <p>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="add" runat="server" ValidationGroup="r" 
            ImageUrl="~/img/add.png" Height="16px" Width="16px" />

                </p>

            </div>
```

and my script is:

```
 $(function () {
  var addDiv = $('#divAdd');
  var i = $('#divAdd p').size() + 1;

$('#add').on('click', function () {

    $('<p><input type="text" size="100" id="p_new" name="p_new_' + i + '"/><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(addDiv);


    i++;
    return false;

});

$('#remove').on('click', function () {

    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }

    return false;
});
```

});

and also the size of the dynamic text boxes i am creating are not changing if i change the size property why is that?

Comment: Use the browser debugger to put a breakpoint on the `if (i > 2) {` line, and check the value of `i`.

Comment: ya i tried to use debugger on those Add image button and remove link,, they are not even hitting up in debugger mode!! I dunno what wrong with this,, although add button is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing to `$(document).on('click', '#remove', function(){})`. `on` has to be binded to static elements in DOM to work properly.

Comment: thanx!! one more question is that why the size of  dynamic input type is not reflecting changes?

Comment: @Aj_sari it's because you use size() and not length(). Use $('selector').length() to get total number of selector elements in DOM. And instead of global 'i', you can use it directly in input field generation string: $('<p><input type="text" size="100" id="p_new" name="p_new_' + ($('#divAdd p').length() + 1) + '"/><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a></p>').append(addDiv);

Comment: @Aj_sari Than try '.length', i always forget how it must be :D

Comment: let it be!! I ll try it later!! How could i proceed to save this dynamic created values to db?? any refernce approaches?

Comment: @Aj_sari ajax or simple form call to PHP script, use PDO for database operations

Comment: any reference for ajax.post would be so much helpful

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function () {
  var addDiv = $('#divAdd');
  var i = $('#divAdd p').size() + 1;

$('#add').on('click', function () {

    $('<p><input type="text" size="100" id="p_new" name="p_new_' + i + '"/><a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(addDiv);


    i++;
    return false;

});

$(document).on('click','#remove', function () {

    if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Here is [**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ar6x9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Since Content is dynamic, You Have to Delegate click event for the removal button

Try this

```
$('body').on('click','#remove','',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
     if (i > 2) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Laws5/)**

Comment: soo if content is dynamic, can't we use 'on' directly on that dynamic link button??

Comment: @Aj_sari : Justinas already answered that...'on has to be binded to static elements in DOM to work properly'

Answer (score 0):

use length instead of size();

```
 var i = $('#divAdd p').length;
```

Comment: seems you will have duplicate id's , basedon your code above. Try using classes instead of id's

Comment: can you paste the html codes that the asp.net is generating?